# how i may cancel markdown block?

Tags: markdown

There is article in markdown bellow. Code block after list is rendered as a part of list. Two separate code blocks is rendered as one. How may I mark end of list or end of code block?
And is there any way to mark in what language code are and get colored code with, for example, http://prismjs.com/ ?

---

- In part two, I’ll speak in detail about the use of pages, hotspots, gestures, transitions and timers and how to set them up for use with TAP. Then, I’ll show you how to start building a click-through prototype in Fireworks, which will later be converted into an interactive iOS prototype.
- In part three, the conversion to a TAP iOS prototype will be covered in detail. I will also share some tips on its use on iOS devices. You’ll get all of the demo files needed to complete the tutorial, as well as an extensive list of related resources on Fireworks and prototyping.

  var fs = require('fs'),
      hogan = require('hogan.js');

  var templateDir = './templates/',
      template,
      templateKey,
      result = 'var myTemplates = {};';

  fs.readdirSync(templateDir).forEach(function(templateFile) {

  ```
  template = fs.readFileSync(templateDir + templateFile, 'utf8');
  templateKey = templateFile.substr(0, templateFile.lastIndexOf('.'));

  result += 'myTemplates["'+templateKey+'"] = ';
  result += 'new Hogan.Template(' + hogan.compile(template, {asString: true}) + ');'
  ```

  });

  fs.writeFile('compiled.js', result, 'utf8');

Answer (score 1):

1. Markdown code highlighting is implementation-dependent. For example *StackExchange* uses [Google Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) with its own `<!-- language: lang-js -->` markers.
2. As I understand markdown rules, you must use a text in the middle of code blocks

   ```
   code block 1
   ```

   some description

   ```
   code block 2
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about prismjs, but in some (most?) mark down flavors you can use the HTML comment hack (`<!--`) or the non-breaking space hack (`&nbsp;`):

- In part two, I’ll speak in detail about the use of pages, hotspots, gestures, transitions and timers and how to set them up for use with TAP. Then, I’ll show you how to start building a click-through prototype in Fireworks, which will later be converted into an interactive iOS prototype.
- In part three, the conversion to a TAP iOS prototype will be covered in detail. I will also share some tips on its use on iOS devices. You’ll get all of the demo files needed to complete the tutorial, as well as an extensive list of related resources on Fireworks and prototyping.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    hogan = require('hogan.js');

var templateDir = './templates/',
    template,
    templateKey,
    result = 'var myTemplates = {};';
```

```
fs.readdirSync(templateDir).forEach(function(templateFile) {

    template = fs.readFileSync(templateDir + templateFile, 'utf8');
    templateKey = templateFile.substr(0, templateFile.lastIndexOf('.'));

    result += 'myTemplates["'+templateKey+'"] = ';
    result += 'new Hogan.Template(' + hogan.compile(template, {asString: true}) + ');'

});

fs.writeFile('compiled.js', result, 'utf8');
```